# spring-cloud-stream upgrade to higher version not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am upgrading my spring boot project to a higher version.
spring parent - 2.2.1 Release to 2.5.5
spring cloud - Greenwich.RELEASE to 2020.0.3
spring cloud stream - to 3.1.3

When I am upgrading my cloud stream to 3.1.3, I am getting the below error when starting my application.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method messageChannelToInputFluxArgumentAdapter in org.springframework.cloud.stream.reactive.ReactiveSupportAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.CompositeMessageConverterFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.converter.CompositeMessageConverterFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: 3.1.3 is already out of support. The latest one is 3.2.4 which is brought by spring-cloud 2021.0.3

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Zhurakousky , Even after upgrading to 3.2.4, I am getting the same error

Comment: Please create a small application that reproduces the issue. The information provided doesn't have anything relevant to diagnose the issue

Comment: I'm running into a very similar problem. I don't know the answer, but I think it has to do with org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration. In spring-cloud-stream 1.x, that config class had a method that would return a CompositeMessageConverterFactory, providing the bean you're looking for. I couldn't find any notes about deprecation, but that method just quietly disappeared in spring-cloud-stream 2.0.0.RELEASE. I think we'll need to just provide our own configuration for that bean now.